# How do I display a date with a custom timezone?

Tags: java, date, timezone, date-format

Lets say I have a string that represents a date that looks like this:

"Wed Jul 08 17:08:48 GMT 2009"

So I parse that string into a date object like this:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
Date fromDate = (Date)formatter.parse(fromDateString);
```

That gives me the correct date object. Now I want to display this date as a CDT value.

I've tried many things, and I just can't get it to work correctly. There must be a simple method using the DateFormat class to get this to work. Any advice? My last attempt was this:

```
formatter.setTimeZone(toTimeZone);
String result = formatter.format(fromDate);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use "zzz" instead of "ZZZ": "Z" is the symbol for an RFC822 time zone.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Having said that, my standard advice on date/time stuff is to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net), which is an altogether better API.

EDIT: Short but complete program:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public List<String> names;

    public static void main(String [] args)
        throws Exception // Just for simplicity!
    {
        String fromDateString = "Wed Jul 08 17:08:48 GMT 2009";
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat
            ("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        Date fromDate = (Date)formatter.parse(fromDateString);
        TimeZone central = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
        formatter.setTimeZone(central);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(fromDate));
    }
}
```

Output: Wed Jul 08 12:08:48 CDT 2009

Comment: Sadly I can't add another dependency without more red tape that I want to deal with. There must be a way to format the time zones using standard java libraries.

Comment: There is, as given in the answer. Just expect more pain if you have to any other date/time manipulation.

Comment: Its not helping. The formatter always spits out the time in GMT and not the reqeusted CDT.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong time zone - it worked fine in my test case. I'll add a short but complete program to demonstrate.

Comment: Yeah, you were right... man that's a pain. Had the correct code the whole time and a typo in my unit test prevented it from working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Using:

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
```

outputs:

```
Wed Jul 08 12:08:48 CDT 2009
```

for the date in your example on my machine. That is after substituting zzz for ZZZ in the format string.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for digging out an old-thread. But I was wondering if there is a java-class that holds all the time-zone-ids as a constant class.
So instead of having to hard-code the time-zone-id while setting time-zone like this:

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
```

we would instead be doing something more standard/uniform:

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(SomeConstantClass.US_CENTRAL));
```

where SomeConstantClass.java is a class that holds the constants referring to the different time-zone-ids that are supported by the TimeZone class.

Answer (score 2):

The modern way is with the java.time classes.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Specify a formatting pattern to match your input string. The codes are similar to `SimpleDateFormat` but not exactly. Be sure to read the class doc for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Note that we specify a `Locale` to determine what human language to use for name of day-of-week and name of month.

```
String input = "Wed Jul 08 17:08:48 GMT 2009";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.ENGLISH );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2009-07-08T17:08:48Z[GMT]

We can adjust that into any other time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `CDT` or `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

I will guess that by `CDT` you meant a time zone like `America/Chicago`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" );
ZonedDateTime zdtChicago = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( z );
```

> zdtChicago.toString() 2009-07-08T12:08:48-05:00[America/Chicago]

## `Instant`

Generally best to work in UTC. For that extract an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

This `Instant` class is a basic building-block class of java.time. You can think of `ZonedDateTime` as an `Instant` plus a `ZoneId`.

```
Instant instant = zdtChicago.toInstant();
```

> instant.toString(): 2009-07-08T17:08:48Z

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).